# Where can I find good Open Source UAV software for a raspberry pi?

Tags: open-source

I hate asking this question here but this is why:

- Aviation Stack Exchange is full of hobby plane enthusiasts
- My question has to do more with coding that it does aviation

That being said, I've looked at the following open source UAV software

- [Paparazzi UAV](http://wiki.paparazziuav.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [Dronecode UAV](https://www.dronecode.org/developers/how-participate)
- [ROS Indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation)

I tried to compile and work with Paparazzi UAV code but their walkthrough failed on my RPi as well as the checked-out source from git.

If any of you know of / have used any open source UAV software please let me know what

Comment: If you are new to compiling on the Pi. My best advice is to just keep trying. Try compile, get an error, search internet for solution to error, fix error, compile again. Also it might be possible that you are running out of RAM, during the compilation, please post the error message in your question.

Comment: @VincentP Are you talking about the paparazzi error? I searched google up and down for the errors, most of which I was able to fix but I ultimately decided it was too much work. The paparazzi community is not very active so I would like to stay in a community that is much more active.

Comment: Have you tried compiling one of the other UAV's?

Comment: Not yet. I wanted to ask the rpi community in case anyone had some helpful info. It seems as though there's not much UAV experience here though so I'll probably end up compiling and trying whatever I can get my hands on. If I don't hear anything back by the time I decide which is best I'll post back here with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what I've got and what I'm going with:

1) Paparazzi UAV is essentially busted and the community is non-existent

2) ROS Indigo is more of a full body robot software seemingly gravitated toward ground robots although it can work for UAVs

3) While getting code from Dronecode I found [APM/Ardupilot](http://ardupilot.com/) which is what I'm going to use.

Comment: Hope you come right, getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

ArduPilot supports running on the RPI if you use an "Erle Brain" or "NAVIO2" sensor cape.  There are other varieties of ways to get it working using sensors just on breakout boards as well.
http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-navio2-overview.html
http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-erle-brain-linux-autopilot.html